# How to fetch properly APIs with Retry-After limitations

Tags: python, request

I am trying to fetch ArXiv API with this code:

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

OAI = "{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}"
ARXIV = "{http://arxiv.org/OAI/arXiv/}"

def harvest(arxiv):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=("title", "abstract", "categories"))
    base_url = "http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=ListRecords&"
    url = (base_url +
           "from=2012-01-01&until=2019-01-01&" +
           "metadataPrefix=arXiv&set=%s"%arxiv)

    while True:
        print("fetching", url)

        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

        xml = response.read()

        root = ET.fromstring(xml)

        for record in root.find(OAI+'ListRecords').findall(OAI+"record"):
            meta = record.find(OAI+'metadata')
            info = meta.find(ARXIV+"arXiv")
            categories = info.find(ARXIV+"categories").text

            contents = {'title': info.find(ARXIV+"title").text,
                        'abstract': 
                         info.find(ARXIV+"abstract").text.strip(),
                        'categories': categories.split(),
                        }

            df = df.append(contents, ignore_index=True)

        token = root.find(OAI+'ListRecords').find(OAI+"resumptionToken")
        if token is None or token.text is None:
           break
        else:
           url = base_url + "resumptionToken=%s"%(token.text)

    return df

df_hep_th = harvest("physics:hep-th")

df_hep_th.to_csv('df_hep_th.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

I get 1000 papers each time and append them on a dataframe. Then I save the df as csv.

I have tried this code before with success, for example to get the results of the category "physics:hep-ex". It works perfect at first, but now I am getting this error and I cannot solve it:

```
  File "C:\Users\my_user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in 
       http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

  HTTPError: Retry after specified interval
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is given because you are doing too many requests in a small interval of time. Take a look at [Retry After](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) HTTP docs. What you should do, is retrieve which is this interval of time `t` and when you get an error, wait for `t` seconds with some delay function and continue running the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is solved if I had in the While: 
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            if e.code == 503:
                to = int(e.hdrs.get("retry-after", 30))
                print ("Got 503. Retrying after {0:d} seconds.".format(to))

                time.sleep(to)
                continue
                
            else:
                raise